# Spring Integration Transformer: Serialize LocalDateTime to Json as ISO String

Tags: java, jackson, spring-integration

Using Spring Integration, I need to transform an object from an external API package to JSON, to finally send it via AmqpOutboundEndpoint. For this, I use ObjectToJsonTransformer.

Issue is with LocalDateTime attributes of that class: They get serialized into integer arrays `[yyyy,mm,dd,HH,MM,ss]`, but I want them to be converted to ISO 8601 date time strings.

I see that this issue is quite common and so far I have added jackson-datatype-jsr310 to the dependencies and set property `spring.jackson.serialization.write_data_as_timestamps: true`, but that did not help.

I need a hint towards a working solution, please.

Edit: Adding source code (package and import lines dropped) and pom.xml:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        List<Data> source = Arrays.asList(new Data());
        ctx.getBean(Demo.class).demo(source);

        ctx.close();
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface Demo {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "upcase.input")
        void demo(Collection<Data> source);

    }

    public static class Data {

        public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime() {
            return LocalDateTime.now();
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow upcase() {
        return f -> f
                .split()
                .log()
                .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
                .log()
                .handle(m -> System.out.printf("%n%s%n%n", m.getPayload()));
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <spring.integration>5.5.15</spring.integration>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-int</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-int</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Well, as far as I know adding that `jackson-datatype-jsr310` should be enough. The `ObjectToJsonTransformer` configures respective module automatically and `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS(true)` is by default anyway. Any chances that you can share with us a simple project to reproduce and play with?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks your feedback, I added sample code and pom.xml. The output of running sample code is: `{"localDateTime":[2022,11,28,18,20,31,599393100]}` (of course, current local time is printed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your expectations are exactly opposite.

The `LocalDateTimeSerializer` has the logic like this:

```
   if (useTimestamp(provider)) {
        g.writeStartArray();
        _serializeAsArrayContents(value, g, provider);
        g.writeEndArray();
    }
```

So, with that `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=true` (which is by default) we indeed are going to have an array of `LocalDateTime` properties.

If you talk about a formatting to the ISO 8601, then you need to do exactly opposite: `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false`. And this configuration modification:

```
public IntegrationFlow upcase(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  ...
  .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer(new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper)))
```

to be able to take a properly auto-configured `ObjectMapper`.

The mentioned `LocalDateTimeSerializer` will do then `LocalDateTime` formatting via its:

```
protected DateTimeFormatter _defaultFormatter() {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
}
```

With this configuration I have the output like this:

```
{"localDateTime":"2022-11-28T13:17:30.4691295"}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't change the output. I don't have a ObjectMapper bean around, so maybe I did something wrong, when doing the following instead:

`.transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer(new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())))`

However, doing so and setting write-dates-as-timestamps to false did not change the output.

Comment: If you do `new ObjectMapper()`, then indeed Spring Boot configuration options does not have any effects. Not sure why you say that there is no `ObjectMapper` bean since the one is really auto-configured for you by Spring Boot. I just did a simple Spring Boot app according to you question and that `upcase(ObjectMapper objectMapper)` injection and respective `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false` in the `application.properties` did the trick for me. If that still doesn't work for you, please, prove it with your own simple project to let me to look into and play with.

Comment: Applying your changes to the demo source above does indeed create the required result (LocalDateTime as String), but for some reason I cannot adopt it the real project. Over there I get "consider defining a bean of type 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.objectmapper' in your configuration". 

Will be something different...