# Spring JPA @CreatedDate Entity column flushing out time LocalDateTime in wrong format

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have created an Entity column like below

```
@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "create_ts", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

This is mapped to a Postgres table with column of type

```
timestamp(0) without time zone
```

Inserts are going in fine with the correct format in the table

> 2022-12-01 01:24:35

Upon doing a curl on the api,

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/profile/111111"
```

the column data looks like below.

```
{"userId":111111,"createdDate":[2022,12,1,1,24,35],"lastModifiedDate":[2022,12,1,1,24,35]}
```

My application.yml below

```
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql=true:
```

Controller

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/{dsid}", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<UserProfile> getUserProfile(@PathVariable Long dsid){

    Optional<UserProfile> userProfile = userProfService.getUserProfile(dsid);
    if (!userProfile.isPresent()) {
        logger.error("User profile not set for user with id: " + dsid);
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Profile", "id", dsid);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userProfService.getUserProfile(id).get(), HttpStatus.OK);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I had the same issue using Spring Integration and the answer might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74569908/spring-integration-transformer-serialize-localdatetime-to-json-as-iso-string?noredirect=1#comment131683975_74569908

Comment: Need more info, what does your response object look like, how do you convert it to string, what does your controller method look like?

Comment: @ChristophDahlen To me, that answer looks correct. Did you try the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to annotate the Entity field createdDate with

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
```

Response after adding annotation.

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "userPreference": {
    "theme": "dark",
    "landing": "myprojects",
    "projects": "112,333,222"
  },
  "createdDate": "2022-12-02 20:28:23",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2022-12-02 20:28:23"
}
```